# Figuring out why heroku app doesn't match local master branch contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm trying to figure out why my heroku deploy isn't identical to my local Rails4 repo. In particular, a number of my migrations aren't copied over, which causes all sorts of trouble when I run the app remotely.

Here are all my migrations (I'm running commands from the root of my local app):

```
ls db/migrate/
20160402152001_create_users.rb                  20160403231740_add_many_fields_to_record.rb
20160402214410_create_records.rb                20160403233848_rename_release_field_in_record.rb
20160402214520_add_attachment_file_upload_to_records.rb     20160407172018_create_contact_forms.rb
20160403000621_change_cas_user_id_to_user_name_in_records.rb
```

But when I run the following commands, I see not all migrations are appearing on heroku:

```
git config --list | grep heroku
remote.heroku.url=https://git.heroku.com/voices-dev.git
remote.heroku.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
branch.master.remote=https://git.heroku.com/voices-dev.git

# make some local changes
touch a
git add .
git commit -m "add dummy file"

# push changes and check the contents of db/migrate on remote host
git push -uf https://git.heroku.com/voices-dev.git master

heroku run bash
ls db/migrate
20160402152001_create_users.rb  20160402214410_create_records.rb  20160402214520_add_attachment_file_upload_to_records.rb
```

Do others know what might be causing some of my local files to not appear on heroku? I'd be grateful for any help others can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good grief, I had added `db/` to my gitignore. I'll leave this here in case others end up going mad as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your local database isn't the same as your heroku database. You have to run heroku run rake db:migrate to get them to match.

Comment: Thanks Cacauzen, but the problem was that some migrations were not copied over to heroku because I had added `db/` to my `.gitignore` file before writing some of the migrations. I didn't notice that I didn't add them to my local master branch before, but this is the explanation for the a-symmetry between my local migration repo and my remote/heroku-hosted migration repo.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it figured out :)